How to call a ASM function from c++
Im trying to call a ASM function from c++ but I get the error unresolved external symbol referenced
my c++ code:
extern void foo();

int main() {
    foo();
    return 0;
}

my asm code:
section .text
global foo
foo:
    ret

I tried adding a _ to the ASM function name and changing the complier to MASM but it still didn't work. Im expecting for it to call the function.

You might need extern "C" on the declaration.  What programming environment are you using and what is the exact procedure you are using to compile the code?  Can you share the exact invocations of the assembler, compiler, and linker that are happening?  Can you share the exact error message?  Also, return 0; isn't needed at the end of main.

Use extern "C" or use the decorated name in your assembly. PS: you forgot to provide the exact error message which should normally include the name of the missing symbol.

Im using visual studio 2022 and just running the application normally. The error messages are "LNK2019 unresolved external symbol foo referenced in function main" and "1 unresolved externals". I tried using extern "C" but it gave me the same error messages.

Then I wonder if the assembly is even getting compiled.  If you write nonsense in it, do you get a syntax error?

I spammed random letters in the ASM file and didnt get a syntax error.

Then this is probably a Visual Studio configuration problem.  I went ahead and added the Visual Studio tag.  You probably have the wrong extension on your ASM file or added it to the project in the wrong way, so it's not even being compiled.  I don't use Visual Studio much so I'll step aside.

I fixed the issue by adding a header file and changing the file extension to asm and changing up the asm code a little bit
C++ code
extern "C" void foo();

int main() {
    foo();
}

ASM code
.code

foo PROC
ret
foo ENDP

END


The asm in the question is the NASM syntax equivalent of this MASM answer, BTW.

Hi, @user24684540 Glad to know your problem has been solved.  See Can I answer my own question? Just a reminder :)
